# Читалка в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Мне нужно чтобы на форме был например Memo или ещё что нибудь, что могло открывать текстовые файлы. Чтобы я выбрал текстовый документ на компьютере в .txt формате и он открывался в этом самом мемо или ещё в чём

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кидаете на форму `TMemo`, `TOpenDialog` и `TButton`. Щелчку на кнопке назначаем следующие действия:

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
```

Всё, можно компилировать.

Щёлкаем по кнопке, выбираем файл, он загружается в `Memo`.

Answer (score 0):

Прошу (я сам сделал): [создание блокнота](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PWFKfZhYUA)